# Shortening blog post address in browser

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I need to shorten address in browser in PrestaShop from "**csblog/post**" to "**blog**". Customer is using blog plugin "CS Blog" which generates both links and addresses.

***csblog*** is module, ***post*** is controller.

scheme of address is /csblog/post/friendly-name

Already tried changing link and address schemes in plugin files and found where exactly it's done, but after changing module and controller - it crushes. It can't find posts or no page error shows.

Already tried various .htaccess Rewrite sentences in main app (in  folder and in main folder of module. No effects.
No help in internet as this plugin seems not very popular.

This is my current code in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ csblog/post/([^&\]+)
RewriteRule ^blog/%1? [L]
```

How can I make this short address, should it be done with .htaccess or managed only via plugin?

Function that generates links:

```
    {
        if (!$id_lang)
            $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
        $id_shop = Context::getContext()->shop->id;
        $url = Context::getContext()->link->getBaseLink($id_shop).$this->getLangLink($id_lang, null, $id_shop);
        $params['module'] = $module;
        $params['controller'] = $controller ? $controller : 'default';
        $dispatcher = Dispatcher::getInstance();
        $dispatcher->addRoute('cs_blog_post', '{module}{/:controller}/{id_cs_blog_post}-{category_parent}-{rewrite}.html', null, 1, array(//{module}{/:controller}
                'module' =>         array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'module'),
                'controller' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'controller'),
                'category_parent' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'category_parent'),
                'id_cs_blog_post' =>                array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_cs_blog_post'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ), array('fc' => 'module',));

        // If the module has its own route ... just use it !
        if ($dispatcher->hasRoute('module-'.$module.'-'.$controller, $id_lang))
            return Context::getContext()->link->getPageLink('module-'.$module.'-'.$controller, $ssl, $id_lang, $params);
        else
            return $url.$dispatcher->createUrl('cs_blog_post', $id_lang, $params);
    }
```

Function that generates blog posts address:

```
public function hookModuleRoutes($params){
'cs_blog_post' => array(
            'controller' => null,
            'rule' =>       '{module}{/:controller}/{id_cs_blog_post}-{category_parent}-{rewrite}.html',
            'keywords' => array(
                'module' =>         array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'module'),
                'controller' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'controller'),
                'category_parent' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'category_parent'),
                'id_cs_blog_post' =>                array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_cs_blog_post'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ),
            'params' => array(
                'fc' => 'module',
            ),
        ),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check on [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/uF7akW/1) to make sure if that would be the redirect you want to do. Then, you want to add a RewriteRul on your htaccess file. Maybe, something similar to this would work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} csblog\/post [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)csblog\/post$ $1blog [NE,R=301,L]

</IfModule>
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
```

[image]

Ever time that you change your htaccess, you may want to clear your browsing history and test it to see if it works.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work in neither main app and module folder. I cleaned PrestaShop and browser cache, also checked in different browser that never been used for this page.

Answer (score 0):

Routing is on your module's main file.

find function hookModuleRoutes on your file (probably csblog.php).
Then you can change your route

Comment: Yes, there's array of routes, I changed rule for post (cd_blog_post) but there is still **{module}{:/controller}/** element that seems to be required. I assumed that 'keyword' parameter is for generating SEO.
Changes give me one of errors: 

1. redirects to 302 page, 

2. shows that page is unavailable

3. takes blogs category parent from URI (generated in this file) and puts it as category folder of products in shop (I don't know why)

4. No entry - when I remove id and category elements from name generation of post

Comment: May you add this function to your first post?

Comment: Added two functions: one that generates links and one generating blog post addresses (it's just a part of function, rest of it generates other addresses in module).